# Calculating the cohomology of a suspension and a quotient

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For a (non hand-in) exercise for my Algebraic Topology course, I have to show that the cohomology groups of the suspension of $\mathbb{R}P^3$ and the quotient $\mathbb{R}P^4/\mathbb{R}P^1$ are isomorphic. The second part of the exercise is to show that the spaces are not homotopy equivalent. However; I fail to find out why the cohomology groups are isomorphic. Let us for now assume we are working with coefficients in the integer to make things a bit easier.

To compute $\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^3$ I have tried the following. By the suspension isomorphism we have that $$\tilde{H}^n(\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^3)\cong \tilde{H}^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}P^3)$$By application of the Universal Coefficient Theorem we get that $$\tilde{H}^n(\Sigma \mathbb{R}P^3)=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&\text{if }n\text{ is 4}\\\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}&\text{if }n\text{ is 3}\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

Good! Now we can try to compute $H^n(\mathbb{R}P^4/\mathbb{R}P^1)$. Because both are CW-complexes, and in particular $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is a subcomplex of $\mathbb{R}P^3$, they form a good pair. Hence we have the isomorphism $$\tilde{H}^n(\mathbb{R}P^4/\mathbb{R}P^1)\cong H^n(\mathbb{R}P^4,\mathbb{R}P^1).$$
However, when I try to compute $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^4,\mathbb{R}P^1)$ using the long exact sequence of cohomology, I get the following exact sequence: $$\ldots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H^2(\mathbb{R}P^4,\mathbb{R}P^1)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0\rightarrow \ldots,$$showing that $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^4,\mathbb{R}P^1)$ can never be zero, and hence can never be isomorphic to the earlier calculated cohomology groups of the suspension of $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Most probably there is a mistake in my calculations, but I haven't been able to spot it yet. Any help is welcome!

Comment: I think you may be right. You can also consider that $\mathbb{R}P^4 / \mathbb{R}P^1$ has cell structure $e^0 \cup e^2 \cup e^3 \cup e^4$, giving me a reduced cohomology of $\tilde{H}^2 (\mathbb{R}P^4/\mathbb{R}P^1) = \mathbb{Z}$, and $\tilde{H}^4 (\mathbb{R}P^4/\mathbb{R}P^1) = \mathbb{Z}/2$, and trivial otherwise.

Comment: I've seen someone ask this question before; I believe the conclusion was that there was a mistake in the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this is incorrect. The correct statement is that $\Sigma^{2k} \Bbb{RP}^n$ has the same homology as $\Bbb{RP}^{n+2k}/\Bbb{RP}^{2k}$ for all $k \geq 0, n \geq 0$.

You need to suspend an even number of times, because (writing $p(n) = 1 + (-1)^n$, we have $H_{n+k}(\Sigma^k\Bbb{RP}^n) = \Bbb Z/p(n)$, while $H_{n+k}(\Bbb{RP}^{n+k}/\Bbb{RP}^k) = \Bbb Z/p(n+k)$.

But $p(n) = p(n+k)$ iff $k \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.